# Can't seem to be able to modarate Facebook comments on my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

Here is an example:
http://www.oneforisrael.org/index.php/blog/144-what-do-jewish-families-do-on-shabbat

People can and are commenting, this is fine, but I can't modarate it... 
Look at my source code, I think I did everything right.

Any help I would love and appricaite!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fix the warnings indicated at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.oneforisrael.org%2Findex.php%2Fblog%2F144-what-do-jewish-families-do-on-shabbat.

Most of the time when you cannot get to the moderation page it is because of incomplete meta data or incorrect app id or admin id.